# Firebase storage stops working after "Unable to create StorageReference" error

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I noticed that if I apply a wrong URL to StorageReference, that gives me "Unable to create StorageReference" error, that's fine, but then I can't connect to the storage anymore, even if I type a correct StorageReference afterward (that gives no error), seems like I need to reset/clear the storage reference somehow.

Here is my code, if I remove the line with the arrow it works perfectly if I leave it as is the code is stuck at
GetBytesAsync and never continues, no catch, no fail.
What I tried- remove the await, using 2 different storageRefernces, resetting storage to DefaultInstance

My code is very basic-

```
string wrongurl= "Not a good url"
string goodurl ="gs://...."
storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

 try{
===> storageRef =storage.GetReferenceFromUrl(wrongurl);}
catch{}  //always caught because wrong url

try{storageRef =storage.GetReferenceFromUrl(goodurl);}
catch{}  //no catch because good

try{
var task2 = await storageRef.GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).ContinueWith(t => t);

if (task2.IsFaulted || task2.IsCanceled)
    {
          Debug.Log(task2.Exception.ToString());
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
    else
    {}
}
catch{} // no catch
```

unity firebase sdk- 6.13.0

Comment: It looks like you filed a bug too, thanks for that! For anyone following along, the most up to date information will probably be here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/656

Comment: Yeah nobody answers there

Comment: I do see that your issue hasn't been triaged, which is unfortunate _but_ in this case I think you have solid repro steps and it's likely going to have to wait for a bug fix. I'm more concerned about "nobody answers that." Have you had repeated bugs not get answered? If you're on twitter would you mind DM'ing @pux0r3 (https://twitter.com/pux0r3) if this is the case?